# how to draw an arc in html 5 canvas element with different starting and end width?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working n canvas elements. i need to draw an arc in that canvas with different start width and end width

```
context.beginPath();

context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);

context.lineWidth = 15;
```

their is no option for changing start width and end width. how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to interpolate between the start and end widths?

Comment: No. i need to draw an arc width at starting as 1 and at endpoint it should be 5. like that i need to do.

Comment: That *is* interpolating the widths :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All canvas path commands draw mono-width strokes.

But here's one way to achieve your effect by repeatedly rotating an "image" of an arc around your starting point. You can create the "image" using an in-memory canvas.

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var c=document.createElement('canvas');
var cc=c.getContext('2d');
cc.beginPath();
cc.arc(0,52,50,Math.PI*6/4,Math.PI*2);
cc.stroke();


for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  ctx.translate(100,100);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI/360*i);
  ctx.drawImage(c,0,0);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do....

1. Get your start and finish values and figure out the number of times you want to sample the difference
2. Use a loop to call `arc()` repeatedly, with different `lineWidth` values ranging from start to finish.
3. If you did it right, it will draw an arc with a width that varies between your start and finish values.

Comment: Hi..alex tough to understand..can you have any jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(30, 70);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(55, 132, 220, 68);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(55, 115, 44, 70);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

How it works? You just join 2 paths of [quadratic curve](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp). And fill it.